# How to POST with JSON Data using EasyCron

Tags: json, post, request-headers

I am trying to post json (as opposed to form data) using easycron. I see there is a Data input, but in the examples it appears to be for querystring or form data `foo=bar&baz=bop`?

I have been trying to do it with headers to no avail:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Data: '{"my":"json"}'
```

I feel like I'm very close as my endpoint is just complaining about the json payload being empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can just put json in the data input. Though you still need to set the response header content-type.

response header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

data:

```
{"my":"json"}
```